# Why is my watch method didn't work in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have two components in one `js` file, file starts with `const EventBus = new Vue();`

I want to send two strings 'username' and 'password' from first component to seconod component, but I can't do it. Where I am wrong?

First:

```
Vue.component('log-reg-modal', {
    data: () => ({
        username: "",
        password: "",
    }),
    watch: {
        username: function(){
            EventBus.$emit('changed_username', this.username);
        },
        password: function(){
            EventBus.$emit('changed_password', this.password);
        },
    }

});
```

Second:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data: () => ({
        username: "",
        password: "",
    }),
    methods: {
        register : function (event) {
            EventBus.$on('changed_username', this.username);
            EventBus.$on('changed_password', this.password);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I just updated my answer to show how to accomplish this without an EventBus as well.. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `EventBus.$on` within the `created` lifecycle method, to "register" receiving the events.

You can also skip the `EventBus` and just use 'built in' event handlers..

***Using Event Bus:***

```js
const EventBus = new Vue();

const LogRegModal = {
  template: `
    <div><input v-model="username" placeholder="Username" />
         <input v-model="password" placeholder="Password" /></div>
  `,
  data: () => ({ username: "", password: "" }),
  watch: {
    username: function() { EventBus.$emit("changed_username", this.username) },
    password: function() { EventBus.$emit("changed_password", this.password) },
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { LogRegModal },
  data: () => ({ username: "", password: "" }),
  created() {
    EventBus.$on("changed_username", val => this.username = val);
    EventBus.$on("changed_password", val => this.password = val);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <Log-Reg-Modal></Log-Reg-Modal>
  <p v-if="username || password"><i>These values were received from the EventBus:</i></p>
  <ul v-if="username || password">
    <li v-if="username"><b>Username:</b> {{username}}</li>
    <li v-if="password"><b>Password:</b> {{password}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

***Using 'built-in' `this.$emit(..., ...)`:***

```js
const LogRegModal = {
  template: `
    <div><input v-model="username" placeholder="Username" />
         <input v-model="password" placeholder="Password" /></div>
  `,
  data: () => ({ username: "", password: "" }),
  watch: {
    username: function() { this.$emit("changed_username", this.username) },
    password: function() { this.$emit("changed_password", this.password) },
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { LogRegModal },
  data: () => ({ username: "", password: "" }),
  methods: {
    handleUsernameChange(val) { this.username = val },
    handlePasswordChange(val) { this.password = val }
  },
});
```

```css
code {
  color: red;
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.second-p {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <!-- ******************************************** -->
  <!--  Notice we are now handling events as props  -->
  <!-- ******************************************** -->
  <Log-Reg-Modal 
    @changed_username="handleUsernameChange"
    @changed_password="handlePasswordChange"
  ></Log-Reg-Modal>
  <div v-if="username || password">
    <p><i>These values were received via </i><code>this.$emit</code> as 'props' on our component using <code>v-on:event_name</code></p>
    <p class="second-p">(using <code>@event_name</code> is shorthand for <code>v-on:event_name</code>):</p>
    <ul>
      <li v-if="username"><b>Username:</b> {{username}}</li>
      <li v-if="password"><b>Password:</b> {{password}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Handlers that are indicated in EventBus.$on should be functions and not props themself.
2. Did you call **register** method before starting the use of the **log-reg-modal** component?

Comment: U mean I should replace it like that `EventBus.$on('changed_username', (data) => {
                this.username = data;
              });`?
And how to call register method for `log-reg-modal`?

Answer (score 0):

`EventBus.$on` methods should be in `created()` functions in according to Vue lifecycle

```
created (){
        EventBus.$on('changed_username', (data) => {
            this.username = data;
          });
        EventBus.$on('changed_password', (data) => {
            this.password = data;
          });
}
```